# Java painting to BufferedImage or ImageIO.write() do not block and png file produced is either blank of half-baked

Tags: java, servlets, png, gif, headless

I'm creating small png files with simple black and white line drawings within the servlet running on Tomcat 7 on Linux CentOS and using frame buffer Xvfb to provide graphic resources. My goal is then to show this png file on the html page returned by the server. What I'm finding is that once in a while (say one picture out of 10) is shown as blank or sometimes even half-drawn. I checked the corresponding .png files on the server and they are indeed generated in these cases either as blank or as half-drawn.

This is  how my code looks (additional complication is that ChimePro is part of the proprietary class library, I don't have its code; it just extends Panel or Canvas):

```
Frame f = new Frame();
ChimePro cp = new ChimePro();
f.add(cp);
f.addNotify();
cp.setBounds(0,0,200,200);

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage (200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED); 
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics()
cp.paint(g);
File ffjj = new File("file.png");


ImageIO.write(bi, "png", ffjj);
```

So it looks as if paint(g) or, perhaps less probable, ImageIO.write() methods are not blocking as they should be doing, and the program goes forward even though the proper file has not yet been created.
It is also interesting that depending on how I point DISPLAY variable before the Tomcat startup - either to Xvfb screen emulating the X environment on the same server, or to some real X display running on the remote machine - the probability of blank or corrupted pictures changes.

Any ideas of how to deal with this issue to insure that my users do not see blank or corrupted drawings?
I'm actually writing small number of short files, so this is not about speed, just about avoiding showing incorrectly drawn pictures.
Would be thankful for any suggestions.

This is the exception (happens only in some drawings arbitrarily - not depending on the contents of drawing but on some tinming probably):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerExceptio
at com.mdli.chime.ChimePro.paint(ChimePro.java)
at java.awt.Canvas.update(Canvas.java:142)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:255)
at sun.awt.X11.XRepaintArea.updateComponent(XRepaintArea.java:60)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:232)
at sun.awt.X11.XComponentPeer.handleEvent(XComponentPeer.java:591)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4937)
```

Comment: There are lots of things that could be going wrong. If the frame is not realised (attached to a native peer), it won't paint properly and cause an error. Because the container hasn't been validated (essentially laid out), it may not appear properly. You should use printAll instead of paint, as printAll is not double buffered, amongst other things. You should also call g.dispose() before trying to save it. ImageIO.read/write is guaranteed too block

Comment: You're going to a lot of effort just to produce a simple black and white line drawing. You don't need the frame or panel, you can draw directly to the BufferedImage

Comment: I think I still need ChimePro instance. I'll try to do it without Frame. But even without Frame, I'll still need to refer to some X windows - like Xvfb, or remote machine; correct?

Comment: I have no idea what ChimePro is doing. In order to use printAll, you don't need the component to attached to a native peer, that's one of its benefits, but you will need to ensure that the component had a size AND has laid out its contents properly...

Comment: So with printAll I'll not need any reference to X11 in any shape or form? Sorry, I'm not very well with this native peer terminology, that's why I'm asking again.

Comment: Does `ChimePro` work in headless environment? If so, you'll get a more stable environment by specifying [`awt.headless=true`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) as a system property, than by using a virtual framebuffer (like `xvfb`).

Comment: No, I guess this was my problem all along that ChimePro does not work in headless environment. As I understand, correct me if I'm wrong, what that means is that it does not work unless I add the ChimePro instance to a frame. I don't know what is the mechanism of it - what did they (this company which wrote chimePro) do so that it does not work without a frame?

Answer (score 0):

Have g.dispose() before ImageIO.write and see if it helps:

```
Frame f = new Frame();
ChimePro cp = new ChimePro();
f.add(cp);
f.addNotify();
cp.setBounds(0,0,200,200);

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage (200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED); 
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics()
cp.paint(g);
File ffjj = new File("file.png");
g.dispose();

ImageIO.write(bi, "png", ffjj);
```

Comment: Won't make (much) of a difference

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can test only in the evening/night time, so I'll try and let you know tomorrow if it worked.

Comment: MadProgramer, I understood you also remmended to do g.dispose(), but here your write that it won't make much of a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you...

1. Set the size of the component
2. Layout the child components of the container if required
3. Use `printAll` rather the `print` as it will attempt to ensure the content is painted fully and doesn't double buffer the process (making it faster)
4. `dispose` of the `Graphics` context once you are completed.

The following shows the panel when displayed on a frame and when printed using the sample code...

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PrintComponent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrintComponent();
    }

    public PrintComponent() {

        Example example = new Example();
        example.setSize(example.getPreferredSize());
        example.doLayout();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage (example.getWidth(), example.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        example.printAll(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("D:/PrintExample.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Example extends JPanel {

        public Example() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(new JLabel("Hello"), gbc);
            add(new JTextField("'ello", 20), gbc);
            add(new JButton("g'day"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try all of it tonight. In the meantime I tried these changes within a standalone application (where I can draw in the file with the picture, but have not yet re-created the problem with blank files),  and it still does not work for me without adding my ChimePro component to the Frame. printAll() and g.dispose() are of course working fine, though I'll need to run it in Tomcat servlet to make sure I don't see these blank pictures.

Comment: Well, unfortunately nothing helped. When I replace paint() with printAll() I get just black screen and nothing else in all pictures (in the normal case they are usually the pictures of molecules drawn as black lines on white background). Disposing of graphics object does not seem to make any difference. looking more attentively at Tomcat logs I actually discovered nullpointer exception within ChimePro painting:

Comment: Well, unfortunately nothing helped. When I replace paint() with printAll() I get just black screen and nothing else in all pictures (in the normal case they are usually the pictures of molecules drawn as black lines on white background). Disposing of graphics object does not seem to make any difference. looking more attentively at Tomcat logs I actually discovered nullpointer exception within ChimePro painting and its interaction with X11. Perhaps this is what causes blank screens. The strange thing is that I used for many years the same component with the older version of Java/Tomcat was OK.

Comment: how can I write more extended comment? I am new to stackoverflow as a partiocipant: was only reading it up to now.

Comment: Okay.  You could try adding `ChimePro` to a `JFrame` and calling `pack`, this would attach it to a native peer and then try calling `printAll` on the instance of `ChimePro` - but it will depend on what's causing the `NullPointerException`

Comment: There's a limit...generally, just keep typing ;)

Comment: The same library works on the same system when I run it as a Java application pointing DISPLAY to all the same locations. It is only under Tomcat that it shows this issue.

Comment: What's the exception say, can you post it to your question?

Comment: I did add it to Frame. without adding to Frame it does not work at all even in the application. So I kept f.add() and f.addNotify()

Comment: Did you call `pack`...this and `setVisible` are the only times Java will create the native peer (the connection to the underlying OS from which the actually Window comes from).  Tomcat could also be running in headless mode

Comment: But then it would not have created any pictures and it fails just intermittently? Can I call setVisible() running on server?

Comment: It depends, `pack` would be my preferred method.  But so long as the server is not running in headless mode it should work.  I'm not sure the `NullPointerException` is related to the painting process though, but I don't have access to the component to know for sure

Comment: Previously I ran the same thing on Tomcat 3 and Java 1.4 and then I used that third party library - I think its is called paj - which was replacing all this X for headless java. Since java 5 that company announced that now Java natively supports headless and stopped supporting that paj.jar. And I was never able to do it with that supposed native support of headless java. So now I need all these frame buffers or DISPLAY, and it still does not work.

Comment: Well, I think you might need to go back to the company, because that's the weak link here and I can't diagnose that problem

Comment: None of them are no longer supported - nor paj,  nor ChimePro.

Comment: Do they really support headless java since java 1.5? Never could understand that. I know you you can declare that it is haedless, but there are still no resources to replace X11, like they used to provide in that paj.jar

Comment: And it all works and does not fail on the same server as application. It is only within Tomcat that it produces these problems. And I can't stay forever with Tomcat 3 and Java 1.4.

Comment: Just absolute zugzwang. No way out of it.

Comment: There are so many things that be causing an issue.  A change in security permissions, running environments, security manager updates, class loading issues, JNI issues...the best people to ask are the authors...

Comment: But security would have prevented it form running all the time. and this happens - just about 1 out of 10 times. Anyawy, thanks a lot for all your help. There is probably no solution to it.

Comment: If only I could somehow diagnose from BufferedImage object itself that it is not right, I could in such cases repeat its generation and reduce the frequency of such pictures to almost zero. By the way, it looks like the exception which I showed above is not correlated with the cases of missing pictures, as I compared the occurences of these errors in the log and they don't coincide with blank gif files generated cases.

Comment: Well, I'll finally count the number of black pixels in BufferedImage and if that number is sufficiently small, I'll re-create the BufferedImage. In this way I should be able to reduce frequency of empty pictures to almost zero. I checked already that it counts pixels fine and gives 0 corresponding to blank gifs. So hopefully will implement it tomorrow in the servlet.